# Instead of the small icon Lollipop displays the launcher icon in the large icon slot

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm testing on Android 4.4 (on a Motorola Moto E) and Android 5.0 (on a Huawei P8 GRA-L09).

Notifications look the same on both in the status bar. When opened, they look different (I don't have enough reputation to post images):

- 4.4 displays a larger (scaled?) variant of the small icon.
- 5.0 displays the launcher icon. It does not even display the small icon as a secondary icon.

I need to display several different notifications and it is not sufficient to see what app they come from.

If I set the large icon (at least in 4.4) the small icon is displayed as a secondary icon, which is useless.

How can I make 5.0 display the small icon as the primary icon?

Answer (score 0):

This must be a bug in the Huawei P8, as the Motorola Moto E does display the icon as expected in Android 5.1 as well. So, to answer the question: There is nothing to do.

Comment: It still does not look like an answer. Probably the iditial question should be edited and updated with this information.